Identify and label each branch in a hierarchical structure
I am creating a cleansing view for a ledger table where transactions are stored with hierarchical structure in the source system. I want to create an additional column 'Group_Id' identifying all the records which belong to the same transaction set.
My goal is to find the most efficient way to populate the Group_Id column like in the following example:



Entry_No
Closed_By_Entry_No
Group_Id




1
4
1


2
4
1


3
4
1


4
5
1


5
0
1


6
9
2


7
9
2


8
9
2


9
11
2


10
11
2


11
0
2


12
14
3


13
14
3


14
0
3


15
16
4


16
0
4


17
0
5


18
20
6


19
20
6


20
22
6


21
22
6


22
0
6



Where Closed_By_Entry_No is the Parent_Id and Entry_No is the Child_Id and the Parent_Id of the top-most Child_Id of each set is always 0 (zero).
The challenge for me is that I don't have one hierarchy in my dataset, I have hundreds of thousand of them. Typically each set is made of two records: 1 invoice + 1 payments (70% of the records in total), but then there are more elaborated situations like in the above example where I can have e.g. 15 invoices + 3 payments + 1 credit note. And I need to identify all of those sets in a way I can treat them as a single subject for further calculations.
The only idea I have now to solve this is feeding a cursor with only
SELECT Entry_No, Closed_By_Entry_No 
FROM table 
WHERE Closed_By_Entry_No = 0

Scroll this cursor through the resultset sending each candidate record to a stored procedure containing the recursive CTE to read the hierarchy from the original table and populating the Group_Id incrementally from the cursor index itself and storing the result in a temp table. Then continue from that temp table ....
There must be a simpler method that doesn't use either cursors or temporary tables.

Could you provide the sample of expected result for the dataset provided??

The expected result is displayed in the above table. My dataset doesn't have any Group_Id column, I want to populate the Group_Id column as in the above example table. I hope this may clarify.

It's a straightforward recursive common table expression:
declare @LedgerEntries as Table ( Entry_No Int, Closed_By_Entry_No Int, Group_Id Int );
insert into @LedgerEntries ( Entry_No, Closed_By_Entry_No, Group_Id ) values
  ( 1, 4, 1 ),
  ( 2, 4, 1 ),
  ( 3, 4, 1 ),
  ( 4, 5, 1 ),
  ( 5, 0, 1 ),
  ( 6, 9, 2 ),
  ( 7, 9, 2 ),
  ( 8, 9, 2 ),
  ( 9, 11, 2 ),
  ( 10, 11, 2 ),
  ( 11, 0, 2 ),
  ( 12, 14, 3 ),
  ( 13, 14, 3 ),
  ( 14, 0, 3 ),
  ( 15, 16, 4 ),
  ( 16, 0, 4 ),
  ( 17, 0, 5 ),
  ( 18, 20, 6 ),
  ( 19, 20, 6 ),
  ( 20, 22, 6 ),
  ( 21,  22, 6 ),
  ( 22, 0, 6 );

select * from @LedgerEntries;

with Hierarchy as (
  -- Anchor query.
  --   Start with the closed by zero ledger entries and assign a group id.
  select Entry_No, Closed_By_Entry_No, Group_Id,
    Row_Number( ) over ( order by Entry_No ) as NewGroupId
    from @LedgerEntries
    where Closed_By_Entry_No = 0
  union all
  -- Recursive query.
  --   Add each level, working backwards, of ledger entries and propagate the new group id.
  select LE.Entry_No, LE.Closed_By_Entry_No, LE.Group_Id, H.NewGroupId
    from Hierarchy as H inner join
      @LedgerEntries as LE on LE.Closed_By_Entry_No = H.Entry_No
  )
  select *
    from Hierarchy
    order by Entry_No;

dbfiddle.

You are quicker ;). I used #tmp_table instead of table variable.

Thanks @HABO, your answer fully address my concern.
